# How to dislplay user email id in Woocommerce Reset Password email?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In Reset password Email, the username is displaying but when I am trying to get email id too. Email id is not showing. The code which is used is pasted below.

```
<?php printf( esc_html__( 'Username: %s', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $user_email ) ); ?>
```

I replaced `$user_login` with `$user_email` to get email id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Use `get_user_by` as below

```
$user_details = get_userdatabylogin($user_login);
$user_mail = $user_details->user_email;
```

Now you got user email in `$user_mail` variable so you can pass it as below

```
<?php printf( esc_html__( 'User Email: %s', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $user_mail  ) ); ?>
```

Tested and works well.